# VBscript Can't Find Excel File

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am attempting to use VBscript to open an excel file. However, when I run the script, it says the file cannot be located. I am pretty certain I have the file path correct. Is it possible that something else is causing my code to fail?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = 
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Projects\1A.xlsx")

Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
```

Comment: *Is it possible that something else is causing my code to fail?* - Highly unlikely. Check your file path and name.

Comment: *"pretty certain"* isn't very definitive, have you double even triple checked?

Comment: In 9 out of 10 cases, this is permission related, the path is inside a User Profile which tends to be locked down, is the script being run with elevated privileges *(if you have confirmed the path is correct I should add)*? UAC can play havoc with this type of thing.

Comment: I am 100% certain I have the file path correct so this has to be the case. Is there any workaround or do I simply not have system permissions?

Comment: Depending on the Windows OS you will need to start the script be it using `wscript.exe filename.vbs` or `cscript filename.vbs` from an elevated command prompt *(Run as Administrator on the context menu)*.

Comment: It works! thanks so much Lankymart. Type it as an answer if you want and ill give it a check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290396/vbscript-cant-find-excel-file#comment81532183_47290396)

> In 9 out of 10 cases, this is permission related

The likeihood is *(if you have already confirmed the file path is correct)* that the VBScript does not have the permission required to access the file path, but due to the way elevation works along with UAC on most Windows Operating Systems means that VBScript doesn't know about the path, so it isn't reported as a access permission error.

As the path in question refers to a User Profile path the chances of it being permissions related increases.

To fix the problem the host process running the VBScript *(wscript.exe or cscript.exe)* needs to be run using elevated privileges. You can do this by opening an elevated command prompt *(`Run as Administrator` context menu option)* and specifying the host process followed by the script path.

Something like;

```
cscript.exe "yourscript.vbs"
```

Answer (score 1):

From a windows command prompt type

```
c:\ dir C:\Users\Guest\Documents\Projects\1A.xlsx
```

The file could have been saved with a different file extension, or if explorer is hiding extensions and a user has provided the extension on save it might be called `1A.xlsx.xslx`

Windows explorer might be hiding data. If you can see it in explorer, right click the file > properties > details.

The **Name** attribute should tell you exactly what the file is named on disk and the **Folder path** should give you the path.

You can combine the two to give the full path to the file on disk

Comment: It says it cannot find the path, which I am assuming means I have the wrong file location. I should know this, but is there a way for me check or the find the file location withing the file to make sure I have it correct? I have just been using windows explorer.

Comment: Both. I have been using windows explorer to find my file location. Is there another way for me to double or triple check my file location?

Comment: Can you see the file in windows explorer? Is the path same as you used in your code?

Comment: @TDoe I've added some diagnostic info to my answer

Comment: Thank you for the help Spangen! I have been able to confirm the file path. The issue must be permissions related.